# how to pass the list as a parameter in python?

Tags: python, list, function, parameters

below is my code to insert item 'value' to the list 'l' after the index i (i.e. i+1).

```
import random


l =[]

for i in range(10):
     list.append (random.randint(1,500))

for i,j in zip (l, range(10)):
     print (j+1,i)

def insert (list l, int value, int index):
     for i in range (l.length-1, index+1):
          l[i] = l[i-1]
     l[index]= value
```

When I run it, it shows the error:

```
def insert (list l, int value, int index):
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Please help me out!

Comment: what language did you learn before writing python :) ? should read python, but seems like book was on java or c/c++

Comment: Yeah, that's not how type annotations work in Python… https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/

Comment: I learnt C++ @Drako

Comment: also when I am calling the function insert [l.insert (l,65,5)]; I get the error TypeError: insert() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given). 
but insert() takes 3 arguments

Comment: :D then please read on python list comprehensions and also remember the python is not strongly typed language, you don't have to indicate variable type

Comment: The current `insert` we see doesn't take anything, since it's not a valid function definition. If you've fixed it up somehow so it actually compiles, and that version doesn't take 3 arguments, you'll have to show us that version.

Answer (score 1):

You had quite a few syntax errors (type declarations if definition, `.length` rather than `len()`) so I have corrected them now.

```
def insert(l, value, index):
     e = l[-1]
     for i in range(len(l)-1, index, -1):
          l[i] = l[i-1]
     l.append(e)
     l[index] = value
```

and we can see it works:

```
>>> l = list(range(10))
>>> l
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> insert(l, 10, 2)
>>> l
[0, 1, 10, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```